# How to keep thread alive until WebBrowser event fires

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a thread with WebBrowser instance and I have attached to it an DocumentCompleted event. But from what I have observed, my event isn't raised, because thread ends before it happens. When I put MessageBox.Show on the end of thread, it gives time for the event to be raised. But how can I make thread wait for it without MessageBox?

```
WebBrowser browser;
        Thread t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            string url = string.Format("webpage.com");
            browser = new WebBrowser();
            browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            browser.Navigate(url);
            browser.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;
            browser.DocumentCompleted += (o, a) =>
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("In DocumentCompleted.");
                List<Status> statusy = new List<Status>();
                IHTMLDocument2 currentDoc = (IHTMLDocument2)browser.Document.DomDocument;
                //parsing the html doc

                string Statuses = "";
                foreach (Status status in statusy)
                {
                    Statuses += String.Format("{0} {1} - {2} --> {3}{4}", status.Date, status.Time, status.Centre, status.Message, Environment.NewLine);
                }
                MessageBox.Show(Statuses);   
            };

            MessageBox.Show("In thread!!!!");
        });
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
```

Comment: What .net version are you on? Is it a console app?

Comment: 4.0, this code comes from console app, but when it works it's going to be in class file (in Windows Forms app, but without access to actual forms).

Comment: Which MessageBox are you using for it to wait?

Comment: You can use a taskcompletionsource for this, this would be alot simpler

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox, I have the reference to windows forms library, but I don't use any forms. I don't intend to display the WebBrowser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that the web browser control requires a proper message loop to work properly. The thread you're launching has no such message loop, so the web browser can't really do much.

The easiest solution would be to simply host the browser control in a form - this gives you easy control over the lifetime of the browser, and an easy way to maintain the message loop (that's what `Application.Run` does).

If that's not applicable for you (that is, you don't want to show any form at all), you'll need to make a form-less message loop. The simplest example using your code:

```
WebBrowser browser;

Thread t = new Thread(() =>
{
  string url = string.Format("google.com");
  browser = new WebBrowser();
  browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
  browser.Navigate(url);
  browser.DocumentCompleted += (o, a) =>
  {
    MessageBox.Show(browser.Document.Title);

    Application.ExitThread();
  };

  Application.Run();
});
t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
t.Start();
```

If you need to wait on the event from some other thread, there's plenty of ways to synchronize. A simple way to pass data at the same time and with a nice `Task`-based interface is the `TaskCompletionSource` class. For example, if I want to await the title of the document asynchronously, it's as simple as this:

```
WebBrowser browser;
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

Thread t = new Thread(() =>
{
  string url = string.Format("google.com");
  browser = new WebBrowser();
  browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
  browser.Navigate(url);
  browser.DocumentCompleted += (o, a) =>
  {
    tcs.SetResult(browser.Document.Title);

    Application.ExitThread();
  };

  Application.Run();
});
t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
t.Start();

Console.WriteLine(await tcs.Task);
```

Of course, this assumes the callee is an async method, but there's plenty of other things you can do with the task - for example, register a continuation.

You don't need to keep a reference to the `Thread` instance - started threads are roots, so they will never be collected.

Answer (score 3):

You **must** call Application.Run().  Not just to ensure your thread doesn't end too soon, it is also required to get WebBrowser to raise its events.  Using the message loop is a standard way in which heavily threaded components, like WebBrowser, ensure that its events are raised on the same thread that created the object.  And it implements the STA contract.

The message loop that MessageBox.Show() uses under the hood to make itself modal is why it works right now when you use MessageBox.  Not otherwise fundamentally different from the message loop that Application.Run() implements.

Use Application.ExitThread() to get the thread to end.  It must be called on the same thread that called Application.Run().  That won't be a problem when you do it in the DocumentCompleted event handler.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen `MessageBox.Show` causing endless trouble in poorly written applications plenty of times, ideally when lots of `Invoke` calls are involved. "See? Now your code is re-entrant. What happens next? Nobody really knows!"

Answer (score 0):

How about setting a flag in the `DocumentCompleted` event handler, and then waiting for the flag to be set where you are currently doing the `MessageBox.Show()`?

Comment: The thing is I can't make Thread.sleep() because it's going to stop the thread (and the event won't fire).

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag. In the `DocumentCompleted` event handler, set the flag to `false`.
Then use a while statement like:

```
bool Flag = true;
 browser.DocumentCompleted += (o, a) =>
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("In DocumentCompleted.");
            List<Status> statusy = new List<Status>();
            IHTMLDocument2 currentDoc = (IHTMLDocument2)browser.Document.DomDocument;
            //parsing the html doc

            string Statuses = "";
            foreach (Status status in statusy)
            {
                Statuses += String.Format("{0} {1} - {2} --> {3}{4}", status.Date, status.Time, status.Centre, status.Message, Environment.NewLine);
            }
            MessageBox.Show(Statuses);   
            Flag = false;
        };
while (Flag) { }
```

Comment: Did you add the code that preceeded this part properly.?

Comment: Yea, thread still works, but flag never changes it's value. Event doesn't fire for some reason.

Comment: And where exactly are you pumping the window messages here? :P

Comment: Nowhere, I'm printing it to console.